# How to find the projected area of a 3d model in MeshLab?

Tags: 3d, area, meshlab

I have a 3d model of an object. How can I find its projected area (from the top view) using MeshLab?

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you can't use meshlab to do that. This problem is not as trivial as it seems, and depends of the geometry of your mesh. Holes can be a problem here if they are oriented in a malicious way.

Said that, you can build an **approximation** to that value using this method. Remember you can use Ctrl-F and start to write the name of the filter to search the filters.

1. Open you mesh in meshlab. In my example I will use this Eagle
   [image]
2. Apply the filter `Convex Hull`. This will create a new mesh that encloses the input mesh.
   [image]
3. Apply the filter `Transform: Scale, Normalize` to this mesh. Apply an scale value of 0 to `Y-Axis` and uncheck the `uniform scaling` tick.
   [image]
4. This is the expected result. It is a mesh that could be used as a shadow for the original eagle. We will compute the area of this "shadow".
   [image]
5. Use the filter `Compute Geometric Measures` to the "Convex Hull" mesh. You will get a lot of text in the log window. Scroll up until you find the line with a value for "Mesh Surface Area"
   [image]
6. The value you want is **half the value** given in this line, because the projected mesh has triangles in both sides. In my example, it is 470499.468750, so the projected area of this mesh is 235249.73

[image]

Comment: Rockcat,Thank you for your help.

Comment: this technic is not precise for retrieving the projected area of complex objects or objects with holes in them like a donut. The convex hull will remove every holes. You will have an overestimated projected area.

Comment: Just as I said in the first paragraph.